# MySqlHelper.Execute exception (C#) - doing something wrong with parameters

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, .net, stored-procedures

I have a WPF/.Net 4.5 C# app, and I'm using MySQL NET Connector 6.8.3. I'm trying to execute a stored proc in a MySQL database, that expects 3 parameters.

The stored proc is as follows:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `storedProc1`(name VarChar(50), surname VarChar(50), age INT)
BEGIN
INSERT INTO table1 (name, surname, age) VALUES (name, surname, age);
END
```

This is my C# code:

```
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
string connString = "server=localhost;database=db1;user id=user1;password=pass1";
MySqlParameter[] parameters = new MySqlParameter[3];
parameters[0] = new MySqlParameter("name", "john");
parameters[1] = new MySqlParameter("surname", "smith");
parameters[2] = new MySqlParameter("age", 35);
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(connString, "storedProc1", parameters);
```

But I'm getting the following error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException' occurred in MySql.Data.dll
>   Additional information: Incorrect number of arguments for PROCEDURE tracker.insert_track; expected 3, got 0.

I can't figure out where I'm going wrong. Any ideas? Thanks...

Comment: try changing the `new MySqlParameter("name"` to be `new MySqlParameter"@name"` etc, then change the query string to be `"call storedProc1 @name, @surname, @age"`

Comment: Silly question, how do I mark your answer as the correct one? Sorry, I'm kinda new to stackoverflow...

Comment: I need to write it as an answer first, there may also be a time delay before you can mark it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the `new MySqlParameter("name"` to be `new MySqlParameter"@name"` etc, then change the query string to be `"call storedProc1 @name, @surname, @age"`.

It may be possible to use ? paremeters to call the procedure in the way you were trying. See [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36484/Working-C-code-for-MySql-Stored-Procedures-IN-OUT) for some information.